# DISTINCT over huge unnest

Tags: postgresql, distinct, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a materialized view (~ 100k rows) with an `intarray` column `feature_value_ids`. What I want is to select all unique ids from that column, based on some conditions over materialized view

This query runs ok, aprox. 30 ms, giving ~ 1 mil rows:

```
SELECT unnest(feature_value_ids) FROM dematerialized_products               
WHERE is_private = 'f' AND product_category_ids && ARRAY [38]
```

However, if I add DISTINCT, query drops to ~ 400ms, giving ~ 5k rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(feature_value_ids) FROM dematerialized_products               
WHERE is_private = 'f' AND product_category_ids && ARRAY [38]
```

I tried to make a recursive query with no luck (~ 35s), like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
  (SELECT min(value_id) AS value_id FROM z)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (SELECT min(value_id) FROM z WHERE value_id > t.value_id) AS value_id
  FROM t
      WHERE t.value_id IS NOT NULL
), z as (
    SELECT unnest(feature_value_ids) as value_id
    FROM dematerialized_products a
    WHERE is_private = 'f' AND product_category_ids && ARRAY [38]
)

SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.value_id IS NOT NULL
```

I guess this is because `z` is evaluating each time recursive query does

Answer (score 2):

Are the `featured_value_id` array values unique inside the array? If not does it make a difference if you give the planner a little hand by making them unique?:

```
select distinct c.id
from
    dematerialized_products
    cross join lateral
    (
        select distinct id
        from unnest(feature_value_ids) u (id)
    ) c
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show execution plans, but obviously the time is spent sorting the values to eliminate doubles.

If `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` shows that the sort is performed using temporary files, you can improve the performance by raising `work_mem` so that the sort can be performed in memory.

You will still experience a performance hit with `DISTINCT`.